# Geographical replication zones in MySQL Cluster?

Tags: mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

In a default installation, data is shared indiscriminately across all data nodes.

Is it possible to specify that certain tables can only be replicated across a specific group of data nodes?

If so, do the tables need to be created on those nodes, or can they be migrated from other nodes?

Comment: I guess it's a hard question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL Cluster tables are spread among all nodes by default.
It is possible to specify a table to only reside on a subset of
the node groups by either setting the number of partitions or
by setting PARTITION_BALANCE (in 7.5). It is not intended to use
this for geographic replication.

It is not possible to specify exactly on which node group these
partitions will reside (at least I don't think, there was some
work in 5.1 to provide NODEGROUP when creating partitions, but
this is not fully supported, so a bit unsure what works here and
what doesn't).

For geographic replication MySQL Cluster supports replication from
one cluster to another cluster. This is using MySQL Replication and
can thus be done selective for certain tables. It is possible to
replicate different tables to different clusters by using multiple
MySQL replication servers inside one MySQL Cluster.